# Find Gaps in range of dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, google-calendar-api

Hi Folks I used google calendars to pull free/busy schedule for users. I want to able to take those range of dates and then output all the gaps into a new array of some sort?

Any direction pointing would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: couldn't you just iterate through those days / or hours, then store the free time in an array?

Comment: Yes but I'm not exactly sure how to check for the overlap since I'm using ranges of dates?

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Get all your dates (as integers) into a sorted (by time) two-dimensional array, noting whether each date is the beginning or end of the timeframe. For example:

```
array = [[1484715564, 'start'], [1484715565, 'start'], [1484715569, 'end'], [1484715587, 'end'], ...]
```

Then, all you need to do is keep track of whether you've gone through as many `end`s as `start`s, and if you have, make note of it!

```
num_starts = 0
gap_start = 0
gaps = []
array.each do |date, which_end|
  if which_end == 'start'
    num_starts += 1
    if num_starts == 1
      gaps << [gap_start, date]
    end
  else
    num_starts -= 1
    if num_starts == 0
      gap_start = date
    end
  end
end
```